# Python - delimited list from file

Tags: python, list

How can I link the city, time, local to one search. Like if I have a function that is called `search` it will search the whole list for city2 only and print only the values City2, Time2, Local2? Is there anything I need to do when I read the file and put it in the list?

**UPDATE **
Is there anyway to rewrite this code so that you have 3 attributes (city, time, local) and save the data from the file to objects in a list? And use a str function to print them?

**Example list**

```
City
Time
Local
--------------
City2
Time2
Local2
--------------
City
Time
Local
--------------
City3
Time3
Local3
--------------
```

**Code:**

```
class gym:
def __init__(self, city, local, time,  ):
    self.city = city
    self.local = local
    self.time = time
    self.city_dict = {}

    def readfile():
        row = "start"
        list = []
        infile = open("data.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")
        while row != "":
            row = infile.readline()
            list.append(rad)
        infile.close()

gym.readfile()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blckknght has given you a good solution that will be very useful if you want to do other things with the data, but for the task you describe - find "City2" and print it, along with its time and local, - you could do it with a simple `grep -A2 City2 data.txt`, or, with Python:

```
with open("data.txt", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith("City2"):
            for _ in range(3):
                print(line.strip())
                line = next(fh)
            continue
```

If you want to find only the first occurrence you can replace `continue` with `break`.

As discussed in comments, you don't have to print the results immediately. You might do this:

```
matches = []
with open("data.txt") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith("City2"):
            matches.append([])
            for _ in range(3):
                matches[-1].append(line.strip())
                line = next(fh)
            continue
for match in matches:
    print("City: {}; Time: {}; Local: {}".format(*match))
```

Comment: @user73379, you can probably just replace the `print` statements with `print(line.strip())` and pass the encoding to `open`, as you did in your code.

Comment: You need to change "line = fh.next()" to "line = fh.__next__()" in python 3. it works now. Thanks

Comment: @user73379 Oh, right, I think I had read about that. You can probably also do `line = next(fh)`, which is nicer. You're welcome. Do consider Blckknght's answer. I originally thought of mine because it had a potential speed advantage if there was only one possible match (and you could `break` immediately after it), but now that you want multiple matches, you have to scan through the whole file anyway.

Comment: Is there anyway you can format the output of this 2 for loops without destroying the line starts with and gets the 2 rows under it?

Comment: @user73379, you don't have to print immediately, you can instead add the lines to a list, or dictionary, and use that with `str.format`.

Comment: Cant get this to work. Can you give some example how it can look like? Tried to follow some guides and can't get this to work.

Comment: @user73379, Added an example. For anything else, please ask a different question instead. It will viewed by others, who may provide better answers, and it will keep this question cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest solution would be to read the entire file at once and split the different parts on the different delimiters. To make your search work, you'd want to create a dictionary mapping from `city` values to the others.

```
from collections import defaultdict

class gym():
    def __init__(self):
        self.city_dict = defaultdict(list)

    def readfile(self):
        with open("data.txt", encoding="utf-8") as infile:
            text = infile.read() # consumes the whole file into a string

        text = text.rstrip('-\n') # strip off any trailing dashes or newlines

        # split twice, first on dashed lines, then on newline characters
        data = [g.strip().split('\n') for g in text.split('--------------')]

        # now, store in dictionary for searching
        for city, time, local in data:
            self.city_dict[city].append((city, time, local))

    def search(self, city):
        for group in self.city_dict[city]:
             print(*group)
```

Comment: +1. But you should check the length of each vector in the list because it will have the additional element "". Otherwise you get this error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)`

Comment: Is there any parameter missing on the read file? And can you explain def search .. is "city" the variable?

Comment: @MortenKristensen Good point, it is a bit tricky to get it to work with messy data. The trailing line of dashes is especially problematic. I'll edit with an fix for most of the errors I can think of.

Comment: @user73379: No, the default mode is "r" if omitted.

Comment: @Blckknght: I agree. The input data file could also be formatted better for parsing.

Comment: In the search function how can you print out like every City2 in the list at the same time with time and local? I don't understand what does that row do?

Comment: @user73379: Um, I guess I was assuming that the cities were unique, and so a search for a given city would find exactly one result. If they're repeated, you'd want a more complicated structure (like a `collections.defaultdict`, perhaps).

Comment: Its not unique. Can i just use a while/for loop and print every results it gets from the file?

Comment: @user73379: If you only want to do your search once, then it would make sense to do the searching at the same time you're reading the file, as Paulo Almeida's answer does. If you expect to search repeatedly for different values, then building a data structure to make the search quick is a better idea. I've updated my answer to use a `defaultdict` to store lists of results indexed by city name. The `search` method will print out one line of `city time local` for each entry that there was for that city in the file. If you want to you could format the output better, `print(*group)` is very basic.

Comment: Hey! is there anyway to rewrite this code so that you have 3 attributes (city, time, local) and save the data from the file to objects in a list? And use a __str__ function to print them? Will update the first post w8

Comment: @user73379: I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking. The loop at the end of `readfile` has the three values and it can save them however you like. Since you mentioned searching by city, I put them into a dictionary keyed by the city. If you want single big list instead, you can of course do that.